# Devolver más de 1 objeto con AJAX en Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Tengo una llamada AJAX que devuelve más de 1 objeto, y eso hace que me dé fallo, pero necesito todos los objetos que me devuelve la query, y no hallo la forma de pasar todo hacia la template. Como se supone que debería pasarlo? He probado a pasar a JSON pero no sé como y las pruebas que he hecho no me han funcionado. Alguien puede arrojar luz sobre este asunto?

```
def getPhotos(request):
    code = request.POST.get('code', '')
    fotos = Photo.objects.filter(photoCode=code)

return fotos
```

**Actualizo:**

Al usar .filter() me saca el siguiente error: **too many values to unpack**

Answer (score 1):

El método `get()` [por definición](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) devuelve uno y solo un objeto o `None` (que puedes cambiar por un Error 404) en caso de no encontrar coincidencias.

Lo que necesitas es usar el método **`filter()`** que te permite obtener un *queryset* con uno o más objetos que coincidan con tu consulta. Esta su la referencia: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters.

Tu código podría verse de esta manera:

```
def getPhotos(request):
    code = request.POST.get('code', '')
    fotos = Photo.objects.filter(photoCode=code)

return fotos
```

> Esta claro que tu pregunta no está relacionada con la etiqueta AJAX, por lo que deberías considerar la posibilidad de eliminarla.

Answer (score 1):

Como lo han comentado anteriormente, se debe usar `filter`, ya que este es un método que permite obtener más de un `object` en el resultado de un `queryset`. Sin embargo, cuando se retornan objetos *JSON*, no siempre es posible serializar todo el objeto.

Puede realizar lo siguiente:

```
def fotos_json(request):
    lista_fotos_json = []
    code = request.GET.get('code', '') # Esto se cambia GET ya que por orden la solicitud debe ser GET
    fotos =  Fotos.objects.filter(photoCode=code)
    # recorre las fotos y las almacena en la lista de fotos json
    for foto in fotos:
        objeto_foto = {}
        objeto_foto["id"] = foto.id
        # Se deberia asignar al dictionary todos los atributos que desee enviar en el json.
        lista_fotos_json.append(objeto_foto)
    # Por ultimo retorna el objeto json
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status':1,
                                        "data":lista_fotos_json}))


    #finalmente desde su plantilla html deberia llamar este metodo de esta manera
     $.ajax({
        "type" : "GET",
        "data": {"code": 555},
        "url" : "{% url 'nombre url para acceder al view' %}",
        "beforeSend" : function(xhr, settings){
            $.ajaxSettings.beforeSend(xhr, settings);
        },
        "success" : function( data ){
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Si es para un ajax, puedes usar los serializadores de django para devolver los resultados en JSON

De esta manera para Django 1.7+

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import JsonResponse

def getPhotos(request):
    code = request.POST.get('code', '')
    fotos = Photo.objects.filter(photoCode=code)
    resultado = serializers.serialize('json', fotos)
    return JsonResponse({'fotos': resultado}, safe=False)
```